# RGB_D Video capturing using Kinect_v1

Tags: kinect, rgb

I am trying to capture video using Kinext 1. I am looking for easiest way to do this operation. What can be easy solution? I looked through stackoverflow and found following code .

```
import freenect
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass   
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)     

def pretty_depth(depth):
    np.clip(depth, 0, 2**10 - 1, depth)
    depth >>= 2
    depth = depth.astype(np.uint8)
    return depth

while 1:

    dst = pretty_depth(freenect.sync_get_depth()[0])#input from kinect
    cv2.imshow('Video', dst)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('b'):
        break
```

How i can i modify above code so that i will have RGB-D video or RGB and depth frames with time stamps .

Comment: Which line is throwing segmentation fault, did you debug it?

Comment: @liquide i think this one     dst = pretty_depth(freenect.sync_get_depth()[0])#input from kinect . Freenect_sync_get_depth

Comment: @liquide rebooting the system solved problem. So but it is not recording videos . How i can capture videos. I modified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the following function:

```
freenect.runloop(depth=display_depth,
                 video=display_rgb,
                          body=body)
```

I saved images using **imwrite** method with argument of **display_depth** function and **display_rgb** function. In body i just killed the freenect .